# equation not well formatted using markdownToHTML

Tags: r, knitr, mathjax, rstudio

Having this code in a test.md file

```
       $$
       \begin{aligned}
       20x 1  \leqt 70

       \end{aligned}
        $$
```

When I use RStudio button **Preview Html** the equation is well formatted using Mathjax.
But when I try to do it using `markdownToHTML` function:
for example

```
      markdownToHTML('test.md', 'test.html'),
```

the equation is not formatted.

The bug is due to the extra blank line after my equation( I can't remove it because the equation is generated using an R chunk and the cat command)

Does Rstudio does any post-processing on `.md` files to remove blank lines between `$$` ?

Comment: Brian, are you sure you can't eliminate that newline? Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RStudio, we actually have our own version of the markdown package embedded which does the conversion from .md to .html. I tried your scenario and was able to reproduce as well. I recommend reporting this to Jeff Horner to see if there is a bug here that he can fix:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markdown/index.html

https://github.com/rstudio/markdown

Josh

Product Manager - RStudio

Comment: Thanks! I Create the issue on github